# Flutter - How to connect void to build widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, void

I am trying to get a new `historyTile()` to be called to the `Scaffold()` each second. I am unsure how to make the void function connect.

Any advice and feedback is appreciated!

Code:

```
class activityTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const activityTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<activityTab> createState() => _activityTabState();
}

class _activityTabState extends State<activityTab> {



  @override
  void historyTile() {

    final now = DateTime.now();
    String tileTime = DateFormat.yMMMMd().add_jm().format(now);
    ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.backup_outlined),
            title: Text('Synced   my_script.pdf   with the cloud.'),
            subtitle: Text('${tileTime}'),
            tileColor: Colors.greenAccent,
          );
        }
    );
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (Timer t) => historyTile());
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(

      body:
      Container(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: historyTile();                 // ERROR HERE
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use listview.builder? If you use it please item counts

Answer (score 1):

You can try creating periodic streams with a Stream Builder widget. If not, the simplest method is to put your widget in scaffold and try calling the setState function periodically with a 1-second timer.

In the StreamBuilder example you should change the widget a bit. Sending the parameter you want to update to the widget from outside will add a little more flexibility to you.

```
return Scaffold(
    body: StreamBuilder<String>(
     stream: Stream.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (x) {
       // Your Action Here
       final now = DateTime.now();
       return DateFormat.yMMMMd().add_jm().format(now);
     }),
     builder: (context, snapshot) {
     String param = "";
     if (snapshot.hasData) param = snapshot.data!; 
     return _historyTile(txt = param);
    }
   ),
);
```

Or you could use your widget in Scaffold Body and periodically set the widgets state in timer callback.

```
class _activityTabState extends State<activityTab> {

String tileTime = "";

...

Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
 setState(() {
   final now = DateTime.now();
   tileTime = DateFormat.yMMMMd().add_jm().format(now);
 });
};

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: historyTile(tileName);                 
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

or just

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: ListTile(
        leading: Icon(Icons.backup_outlined),
        title: Text('Synced   my_script.pdf   with the cloud.'),
        subtitle: Text('$tileTime'),
        tileColor: Colors.greenAccent,
      ),                 
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

---

Create your historyTile widget as a custom widget

```
class HistoryTile extends StatefulWidget {
  const HistoryTile({Key? key, required this.txt}) : super(key: key);
  final String txt;

  @override
  State<HistoryTile> createState() => _HistoryTileState();
}

class _HistoryTileState extends State<HistoryTile> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListTile(
      leading: Icon(Icons.backup_outlined),
      title: Text('Synced   my_script.pdf   with the cloud.'),
      subtitle: Text(widget.txt),
      tileColor: Colors.greenAccent,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I am new to Dart and am unfamiliar with some concepts. What is an example of a parameter that could be written for param?

Comment: Hello mate, i edited the answer. Feel free to ask anything ^^

Answer (score 0):

there is some issues in you `ListView.Builder`. You do not put `itemCount` there. And you need to use `setState` in timer. So codes are below. Please check.

```
class activityTab extends StatefulWidget {
  const activityTab({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<activityTab> createState() => _activityTabState();
}

class _activityTabState extends State<activityTab> {
  String _now;
  Timer _everySecond;

  @override
  historyTile() {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    String tileTime = DateFormat.yMMMMd().add_jms().format(now);
    return ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        itemCount: 1,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.backup_outlined),
            title: Text('Synced   my_script.pdf   with the cloud.'),
            subtitle: Text('${tileTime}'),
            tileColor: Colors.greenAccent,
          );
        });
  }

  void _timer() {
    Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) {
      setState(() {
        _timer();
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: 500,
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: historyTile(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```